# How to open a new popup window when a user closes fancybox model box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to display a model box(fancy box) and when user clicks on close button or ESC key a new popup window should be displayed. I figured out onclosed trigger can be used but not able to implement it. (I'm beginner in coding)

```
$.fancybox.showLoading();  // show loading
            setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
                $.fancybox({'onClosed' : function() { window.open("https://www.google.com"); }});
            }, 500); // .5 second   
        }, seconds_pop); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on fancybox3, you should implement it with:

```
afterClose: function(){
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
}
```

You can see reference here: [fancybox options](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options)

look up this line `afterClose: $.noop, // After instance has been closed`

Here is my [codePen](https://codepen.io/urmajesty516/pen/YOMmyV) example 
.

Remember to allow popup window on the top right corner after you close the imagebox.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using v2, but you can freely upgrade to v3 and use something like this:

```
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
  beforeClose: function(instance, current) {
    current.opts.animationEffect = false;

    $.fancybox.open({
      type : 'html',
      src : '<div>Hello!</div>',
      animationEffect : false,
      beforeClose : function(instance, current) {
        current.opts.animationEffect = "fade";
      }
    });
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLVqPK?editors=1010

You can choose to use `beforeClose` or `afterClose` callback and to switch animation effects for seamless content change or not.